# How to merge the array property of an object based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

How to merge two objects together. And add new object into body every time when number is matched? 
I tried spread operator but it was overwriting the value instead of changing it.

**Before:**

```
let obj = {
  number: "123",
  body:[
    {
      id:'client',
      text:'hi'
    }
  ]
}

let obj2 = {
  number: "123",
  body:[
    {
      id:'client',
      text:'Hello there'
    }
  ]
}
```

**I need to merge them to have:**

```
obj = {
  number: "123",
  body:[
    {
      id:'client',
      text:'hi'
    },
    {
      id:'client',
      text:'Hello there'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use `concat()` to concatenate arrays.

Comment: You can do it with the spread operator: `new_array = [...array1, ...array2]`. Show what you tried.

Comment: Do you have just two objects (`obj` and `obj2`) or an array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the `number` key is equal in both case then iterate `obj2.body` and push each item in `obj.body`

```js
let obj = {
  number: "123",
  body: [{
    id: 'client',
    text: 'hi'
  }]
}

let obj2 = {
  number: "123",
  body: [{
    id: 'client',
    text: 'Hello there'
  }]
}

if (obj2.number === obj.number) {
  obj2.body.forEach(item => {
    obj.body.push(item)
  })
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: you can use `concat()` instead of a loop.

Comment: @Barmar yeah but actually you already answered before me , so just don't want to repeat

Answer (score 0):

If there are just two objects, you could do it like this

```
if (obj.number == obj2.number) {
   obj.body = obj.body.concat(obj2.body)
   console.log("Here's is your new object", obj);
}
```